# Preview Shows Actionbar but AVD doesn´t

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, manifest

in Preview the Actionbar is visible but in AVD not, i don´know why.

How to make Actionbar visible in Device also?

I  tried several changes like deleting the Apptheme.NoActionBar...but don´t works.

Any Idea? here´s my Code:

**Manifest**

```
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FahrzeugActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fahrzeug"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity android:name=".WebActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity.xml    and    Activity.class**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_fahrzeug"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ibas.locatixteamviewer.FahrzeugActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/fahrzeug_webView" />

</RelativeLayout>



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fahrzeug);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fahrzeug_webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //Javascript erlauben bzw. aktivieren
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //Diese Zeile, damit wir unsere App verwenden für die Webiste und nicht irgendein Browser geöffnet wird.
    webView.loadUrl("Link..."); //?m=1&u=Gast&p=Gast
    //webView.loadData("<html> <body> <h1> Hallo habibi </h1> <p> Das ist meine Testpage!!! </p> </body> </html>" , "text/html", "UTF-8"); //eigene Website anzeiogen durch HTML Code

    webView.canGoBack();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fahrzeug, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.map_tab:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.list_tab:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return true;
        case R.id.web_tab:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What can i do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No screenshots of code please. Include all code directly in the question

Comment: Thanks, please see my Updated Post.